# Difference between MySQL (SQL) SUBSTR - ORDER BY statements

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me understand the difference between the following 2 SQL statements, where the difference is in the way `ORDER BY` using `SUBSTR` is performed:

Query 1:

```sql
SELECT * FROM countrylanguage 
ORDER BY SUBSTR(Language,-3,3)
LIMIT 10;
```

Query 2:

```sql
SELECT * FROM countrylanguage
ORDER BY Language LIKE '%___'
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: those two are not at all alike in how they order; how about telling us what you are actually wanting to acheive?

Comment: `SUBSTR(Language,-3,3)` results in a string, by which you order the rows. `Language LIKE '%___'` results in a boolean instead, so your `ORDER BY` only separates the matches from the mismatches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use SUBSTR after ORDER BY you order result of your query by some part, in this case STRING. If you query SUBSTR(Language,-3,3) th result is ordered by letters of Language values not by first letter as usual but by last 3 letters.

Normal result:
ARABIC,
FRENCH,
GERMAN

Result of your query
ARA**BIC**,
GER**MAN**,
FRE**NCH**

When you use %Like the matching is fuzzy, for exmaple if you query LIKE "%ENGLISH", result is:
AMERICAN ENGLISH,
BRITISH ENGLlISH,
SOUTH AFRICAN ENGLISH

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY substr(language, -3, 3)` order the results lexicographically by the last three characters of the values of the column `language`, if the values is at least three characters long. For all rows where the value is shorter than three characters, `substr(language, -3, 3)` will yield the empty string, so these rows go to the top.

As `LIKE '%___'` matches all strings with at least three characters -- the `'%'` wildcard means any character an arbitrary number of times (also zero times) and `'_'` any character exactly one time -- `ORDER BY language LIKE '%___'` puts the rows where the value of `language` is less than three characters long at the top, the ones where the values is at least three characters long at the bottom.

Rows where `language` is `NULL` are put atop in both cases.